# curl pass authentication using variable

Tags: bash, variables, curl

Any suggestions how to pass authentication using variable in curl?

This is what I have, tried playing without quotes, but no luck.

> ```
>  curl -X GET "https://example.com/site" \
>  -H 'x-auth-email: "${API_EMAIL}"' \
>  -H 'x-auth-key: "${API_KEY}"' \
>  -H "Content-Type: application/json"
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell variables are only expanded within double quotes, not within single quotes:

```
curl "https://example.com/site" \
 -H "x-auth-email: \"${API_EMAIL}\"" \
 -H "x-auth-key: \"${API_KEY}\"" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Comment: Ha, I missed that. This is almost certainly the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
--user "${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}"
```